# pthreads C program hangs at execution

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I'm writing a program that performs gaussian elimination given an A and B matrix. I first grab divisor and multipliers, create pthreads which execute in gauss function which perform their operations on a single 'column'. Then I call main which generates new divisor and multipliers and passes back for another round of operations by the same threads. Using condition pthread vars to accomplish this.

The code hangs until I create a breakpoint which it then proceeds and finishes. Not sure what's holding it up. Could use some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//Need one mutex variable and two condition variables (one c var for
//communicating between threads, and one c var for communicating with main).
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condM = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
float arr[3][4] = {{2,-3,1, -22},{7,9,-3, 14},{6,7,2,91}};
float mults[3];
float divisor;
int num_items = 3;

void* gauss(void *mine)
{
    int thread_count=0;
    int x = *((int *)mine);

    for(int i=0;i<num_items;i++)
    {
        /*do something*/
        arr[i][x] = arr[i][x] / divisor;

        for(int k=0;k<num_items;k++){
            if(k!=i)
                arr[k][x] -= mults[k] * arr[i][x];
        }

        /*lock || wait || signal*/
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        thread_count++;
        if(thread_count < num_items)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mut);
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&condM);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mut);
            thread_count = 0;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int i, j;
    pthread_t threadr[num_items+1];     /*thread id array */
    int is[num_items+1];
    printf("Test");

//    /*input num items*/
//    printf("input the number of items ");
//    scanf("%d",&num_items);
//    
//    /*input A array*/
//    printf("input A array\n");
//    for(i=0;i<num_items;i++)
//        for(j=0;j<num_items;j++)
//            scanf("%f",&arr[i][j]);
//    
//    /*input B array*/
//    printf("input B array\n");
//    for(i=0;i<num_items;i++)
//        scanf("%f",&arr[i][num_items]);

    /*grab first divisor & multipliers*/
    divisor = arr[0][0];
    for(i=0;i<num_items;i++)
    {
        mults[i] = arr[i][0];
    }

    for(i=0;i<num_items+1;i++)
    {
        is[i]=i;
        if(pthread_create(&threadr[i],NULL,gauss,(void *)&is[i]) != 0)
            perror("Pthread_create fails");
    }

    for(i=1;i<num_items;i++)
    {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        pthread_cond_wait(&condM,&mut);

        divisor = arr[i][i];
        for(j=0;j<num_items;j++)
        {

            mults[j] = 1;
            if(j != i)
                mults[j] = arr[j][i];
        }
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }

    printf("The X values are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<num_items; i++) {
        printf("%0.3f \n", arr[i][num_items]);
    }

    /*wait for all threads*/
    for(i=0;i<num_items+1; i++)
        if (pthread_join(threadr[i],NULL) != 0)
            perror("Pthread_join fails");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't explain the hang, but do note that it is not safe to unconditionally choose the elements of the main diagonal as divisors.  These can be zero (even for non-singular systems), and / or have extreme values that make your approach numerically unstable.

Comment: Right, I was going to tackle that problem post hang issue. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition (at least one), and your code does not use its condition variables correctly.  You can probably fix the former by fixing the latter.  Also, I suspect that you intend `gauss()`'s local variable `thread_count` to be shared, but variables with no linkage are not shared.

First, the race condition.  Consider the main thread: it starts the three other threads, and then locks the mutex and waits for condition variable `condM` to be signaled.  But suppose the threads all manage to signal `condM` before the main thread starts waiting?  Condition variable operations are immediate -- any signals to `condM` that occur before `main()` is waiting on it are lost.

Now let's shift gears to talk about condition variables.  As [the Linux manual for `pthread_cond_wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) puts it:

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` functions may occur. Since the return from `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

In other words, condition variables are used to suspend thread operations pending a given condition becoming true.  In abstract terms, that condition is always "it's ok for this thread to proceed", but that's realized in context-specific terms.  Most importantly, the fact that a thread wakes from its wait never inherently communicates that the condition is true; it merely indicates that the newly-woken thread should *check* whether the condition is true.  Generally, the thread should also check before waiting for the first time, as the condition may *already* be true.

In pseudocode, that looks like this:

Thread 1:

```
lock mutex;
loop
    if is_ok_to_proceed then exit loop;
    wait on condition variable;
end loop
// ... maybe do mutex-protected work ...
unlock mutex
```

Thread 2:

```
lock mutex
    // ... maybe do mutex-protected work ...
    is_ok_to_proceed = true;
    signal condition variable;
unlock mutex
```

Generally speaking, there is also (mutex-protected) code somewhere else that make the CV predicate false, so that sometimes the threads indeed do execute their waits.

Now consider how that applies to the race condition in `main()`.  How does `main()` know whether to wait on `condM()`?  There needs to be a shared variable somewhere that answers that for it, and its wait must be conditioned on the value of that variable.  Any thread that means to allow the main thread to proceed must both set the appropriate value for the variable and signal `condM`.  The main thread itself should set the variable, too, as needed, to indicate that it is *not* ready, at that time, to proceed.

Of course, your other CV usage suffers from the same kind of problem, too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This made perfect sense and solved my issue. I better understand cond_vars as well.